# Does azure data factory support real time copy activity?

Tags: azure, android-activity, copy, real-time, azure-data-factory

I want to copy data from an on-premise oracle db to sql server on a real time basis.

Comment: Have a look at Attunity Replicate.

Answer (score 1):

Data Factory has many strengths, but frequency is not one of them. Have you considered a different approach?

For real time integrations I would recommend Functional App, Logic App and/or Service Bus. I would call this App whenever there is a relevant change in the oracle DB. Alternatively you could have an API on top of this on-premise oracle DB that you call from a scheduled APP.

If you expect heavy traffic you might want to consider using a Service Bus. The illustration below shows how Azure Service Bus sends data from a Publisher(on-premise) to a Subscriber(Azure sql DB) using Topic Message.

[Illustration of large scale service bus dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JedWv.png)

Ref. [Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/)

Answer (score 0):

You could copy data incrementally. But there is frequency limitation. Please reference this post. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/54380f98-716b-4a95-88af-cad2ab7e47b5/what-type-of-data-ingestion-does-azure-data-factory-use?forum=AzureDataFactory